# How to improve performance of a query matching on the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, query-performance

I have a requirement to find potentially matching customer records in the same table. The logic is as per below. However this seems to perform at O(N²). Is there anyway to improve the performance here? I've tried setting indexes, hashing the columns and comparing on that, etc but performance remains terrible over a large dataset. I've also added the query plan below.

```
SELECT
    C1.CustomerId AS Customer1, 
    C2.CustomerId AS Customer2
FROM Customer C1
INNER JOIN Customer C2
    ON 
    C1.CustomerId != C2.CustomerId
    AND
    (C1.FirstName = C2.FirstName OR C1.BirthDate = C2.BirthDate)
    AND
    (
        C1.EmailAddress = C2.EmailAddress
        OR
        C1.MobilePhoneNumber = C2.MobilePhoneNumber
        OR
        (
            C1.HomeAddressLine1 = C2.HomeAddressLine1
            AND
            (
                C1.HomePostCode = C2.HomePostCode
                OR
                C1.HomeSuburb = C2.HomeSuburb
            )
        )
    )
```

[image: Query Plan]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split your query into two different queries allowing for two different covering indexes to help you find the rows faster.

One query that checks `FirstName` and another that checks `BirthDate`.

```
select C1.CustomerId,
       C2.CustomerId
from dbo.Customer as C1
  inner join dbo.Customer as C2
    on C1.CustomerId <> C2.CustomerId and
       C1.FirstName = C2.FirstName and
            (
              C1.EmailAddress = C2.EmailAddress or 
              C1.MobilePhoneNumber = C2.MobilePhoneNumber or 
              (
                 C1.HomeAddressLine1 = C2.HomeAddressLine1 and
                (C1.HomePostCode = C2.HomePostCode or C1.HomeSuburb = C2.HomeSuburb)
              )
            );


select C1.CustomerId,
       C2.CustomerId
from dbo.Customer as C1
  inner join dbo.Customer as C2
    on C1.CustomerId <> C2.CustomerId and
       C1.BirthDate = C2.BirthDate and
            (
              C1.EmailAddress = C2.EmailAddress or 
              C1.MobilePhoneNumber = C2.MobilePhoneNumber or 
              (
                 C1.HomeAddressLine1 = C2.HomeAddressLine1 and
                (C1.HomePostCode = C2.HomePostCode or C1.HomeSuburb = C2.HomeSuburb)
              )
            );
```

The index you need to support those queries:

```
create nonclustered index IX_FirstName on dbo.Customer(FirstName) 
  include(EmailAddress, MobilePhoneNumber, HomeAddressLine1, HomePostCode, HomeSuburb);

create nonclustered index IX_BirthDate on dbo.Customer(BirthDate) 
  include(EmailAddress, MobilePhoneNumber, HomeAddressLine1, HomePostCode, HomeSuburb);
```

In my rather limited test case I saw an improvement from more time than I care to wait down to 4 seconds*.

The query plans I got for the two queries.

[image]

[image]

<sub>*I actually started the original query and forgot about it. Scratched my head trying to figure out why my computer was sluggish and found that the query had been running for 40 minutes.</sub>

Comment: what if I use C1.CustomerId > C2.CustomerId ?I think C1.CustomerId <> C2.CustomerId will return more rows .Please clarify it.

Comment: Worth adding a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to make it "one" query again?

Comment: Sure, whatever fits the need of OP. I guess a UNION (removing duplicates) best mimic the original query.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise splitting it up like that would make such a difference. Ran over 1.6 mil records and it took approx 50 mins which is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

An important thing to keep in mind is that hash and merge join are only options when you have an unconditional equality join condition. Consider a simpler version of your query:

```
SELECT
    C1.CustomerId AS Customer1, 
    C2.CustomerId AS Customer2
FROM Customer C1
INNER JOIN Customer C2
    ON C1.FirstName = C2.FirstName OR C1.BirthDate = C2.BirthDate
OPTION (HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN);
```

It is not possible to generate a query plan with hints that disable loop join:

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>
> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
>   defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
>   and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

The `OR` logic means that there's nothing suitable to be hashed or to sort on. When you have a complex join clause without any unconditional equality conditions you tend to get a cross join like you posted in your question. If the table has N rows then you can expect N * (N + 1) rows to be scanned.

A good option is to rewrite the query so that each part has an equality condition (which preferably isn't too many-to-many). Splitting the query on `C1.FirstName = C2.FirstName OR C1.BirthDate = C2.BirthDate` and using `UNION` seems to be your best bet. Both pieces of the query will be eligible for all three join types and you can add indexes as necessary.

It is possible to get the original query to a combination of index seeks but it might require query hints. With the following very basic indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX FN ON Customer (FirstName) INCLUDE (CustomerId);
CREATE INDEX BD ON Customer (BirthDate) INCLUDE (CustomerId);
```

And a `FORCESEEK` query hint I get a query plan like this:

[image: okay query plan]

That query plan isn't necessary great, but it's probably better than the cross join version.

Comment: Did not know about the different join types (hash, merge, nested). Thanks.